# Make Helm overriding manually edited environment variables

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-helm

Using Helm template I can specify deployment environment variables.

However, if the environment variable gets modified manually via Openshift web console, it will be ignored by Helm on upgrades even if the template code changes.

The command I use is

```
helm upgrade --install --force --debug app .
```

templates/deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: app
        image: app:latest
        env:
          - name: ENV
            value: {{ Values.env }}
```

values.yaml

```
env: dev
```

How can I make Helm always override environment variables on upgrade?

Comment: Please, upvote/accept the answer to let community know about the usefulness, thanks!

Comment: @aga there is no answer to be accepted here, because there is no answer that would actually answer the question!

Answer (score 0):

To customize the chart values, you can use:

- `--values` / `-f` to pass in a yaml file holding settings,
- `--set` to provide one or more key=val pairs directly,
- `--set-string` to provide key=val forcing val to be stored as a string,
- `--set-file` to provide key=path to read a single large value from a file at path.

To edit or append to the existing customized values, add the `--reuse-values` flag, otherwise any existing customized values are ignored.

In your case, you can export the variable and use it while running helm upgrade:

```
$ export ENV=change
```

It is possible to easily override variable by adding a `--set` flag in call to helm upgrade:

```
$ helm upgrade --set env=$ENV ./mychart
```

`--set` flag has a higher precedence than the default `values.yaml` file.

I reccomend you to read more about helm upgrade flags from following [documentation](https://github.com/helm/helm/blob/master/docs/helm/helm_upgrade.md) and [article](https://medium.com/@kcatstack/understand-helm-upgrade-flags-reset-values-reuse-values-6e58ac8f127e).

Comment: thanks, however, I'm having issue with manually edited environment variables get persisted